# How to copy over RDS to an Elastic Beanstalk clone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I clone an environment in Elastic Beanstalk, the content of the RDS database on the environment doesn't come onto the clone. Is there a good way to get this behavior?

I have a snapshot of the original RDS database but I can't restore it to the exising environment. Also, in the EBS environment, I can't specify a new RDS database for that environment to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of clarifying things...first, Elastic Beanstalk is abbreviated EB, as EBS stands for Elastic Block Store. Second, EB instances are wholly separate from RDS instances, so you'll need to "clone" the RDS instance separately. And finally, the concept of restoring RDS snapshots is a little different than in other RDBMS systems - restoring a snapshot creates an entirely new RDS instance. There is no way to replace the data in-place.

So, I would recommend that you restore the snapshot and then point your cloned EB instance at the new RDS instance by setting the RDS_HOSTNAME environment variable to the new endpoint.